# Why do Chabad tallis katans have no fringe along the bottom?

Tags: tzitzis, chabad, tallit-katan

Every Chabad tallis katan I have seen does not have fringes along the bottom, but it seems popular to have them on other types of tallis katans, particularly other Chassidishe ones.

[image: Ashkenazi Tallis Katan (Ben's Tallit Shop)]

Here's a normal Ashkenazi tallis katan. See the fringes along the bottom? (Photo courtesy of Ben's Tallit Shop)

[image]

Or here's a rather large picture of a Chassidishe man wearing a tallis katan, where you can obviously see the fringes. (Photo courtesy of Wikipedia)

But when you see Chabad tallis katans, I've never seen one with fringes like this! I notice that most (if not all) Chabadniks wear their tallis katan under the shirt, and so there is no need for the decorative fringes, I guess.

But has anyone ever seen one with fringes along the bottom?

Comment: Your title asks "Why [don't they have fringes]?" but the body of your post asks " has anyone ever seen one with fringes along the bottom?" Which is it?

Comment: @DoubleAA - only so much can fit in the title. I mean both.

Comment: Titles are just catchy things to get peoples attention and give them a sense what's going on. A post should be fully understandable without a title. The body of the post is where _everything_ important should be. Not "only so much can fit" in the body. Use it to say what you want.

Comment: I've closed this because it's unclear what you mean to ask. Please edit in light of the comments above.

Comment: Very confused. Your picture of a " normal Ashkenazi tallis katan" but it doesn't look like the ones I wear. Then you ask if anyone has ever seen one with the fringes -- sure I have -- in the pictures you posted. If you want one with fringes, why not just buy one with fringes? http://tzitzit.tallit-shop.com/wool-talit-katan/

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no requirement about the tufted fringe. This is simply a style or fashion element to the actual garment. The mitzvah component is the tzitzit, not the tufted fringe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I not only saw them, I used one (Chabad and fringes) everyday,

I used then to seperate the front from back (the one I have has fringes on one side), it seems more popular in smaller sizes (maybe it is not so popular in Chabad becouse it is considered by some childish/cute...)

At home people sometimes walk without their shirt on, and in the mikva they can also be seen, some people untuck their shirts all day so that it is warn on them not smashed together by their pants into a scarf

Bli neder I will get a better (cleaner/new) picture up soon

[image]

Comment: Great...how do I get one? I want to wear my tallis katan over my shirt and under my vest (as in the picture I provided) but I follow the Chabad minhag and I prefer the fringes.

Comment: @EzraHoerster I got mine in Jerusalem by Maia shearim/geula from mishkan hatchelet, what size do you need?

Comment: @EzraHoerster you can call to double check but it seems if you choose 2 holes it will be the Chabad one here http://www.mishkan-hatchelet.co.il/134--

Comment: @EzraHoerster no from the photos it seems that the 2 holes are straight not diagonal 45° so probably you will need to call them to make your order, I might have some new ones from them

Comment: size 6 us size 24

Comment: @EzraHoerster I have (see photo above), I need to figure out the price, I have 2 sizes of strings thick and the usual (thin), will you be tying them yourself?

Comment: To be quite honest, my current tallis katan is, B''H, perfectly fine for now. So in other words, I do not need one currently. I was wondering for future. Am I able to contact you somehow when I need one?