# What is the reason for all the FRINGES along the edges of the Tallit Gadol

Tags: tallit-gadol

What, if any, is the significance of all the fringes along the edges of the Tallit Gadol?

[image: Fringes]

<sup>Image from: https://tallit-shop.com</sup>

(I completely understand the commandment concerning Tzitzit on the four corners of the Tallit Gadol.)

Comment: related: [Why do Chabad tallis katans have no fringe along the bottom?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/78094/why-do-chabad-tallis-katans-have-no-fringe-along-the-bottom)

Comment: I have no sources, but the material is woven "horizontally," so it doesn't fray at the top (on the side of the _atara)_ and the bottom, bot on the other two edges you need to do something. Since before the sewing machine it was easier to knot the yarn  (and it looks cooler), I suppose they chose this solution.

Comment: @Kazibácsi that makes good sense. My WOOL adult Tallit Gadol has exactly that. I just looked.  BUT the much smaller Tallit Gadol that I received for my Bar Mitzvah is of a very silky, satany material and is lock-stitched around the edges. The fringes have been braided is as a sort of decoration.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12569/759

Comment: I assume that is of some artificial yarn and satin weaving is not fraying that much (and machine sewed finishing seams are easier/quicker/cheaper to be done).

Comment: Weighing in on the dupe suggestion. Unfortunately that question isn't as clear as this one. The upvoted answer there kind of proves it.

Comment: In all likelihood there is nothing religious about them. Search the internet for Turkish Shawl Fringes. In ancient times cleaning clothes, which included beating them while wet, caused the threads to separate. Edges of the strings that made up the material were left hanging so that one could pull those fringes thereby tightening the material. Sometimes those fringes were knotted so they themselves didn't do more harm than good aa far as keeping the material together.

Comment: Conservative and Reform shuls tend to use tallit "scarves". (Separate problem regarding if these may be considered valid "tallitot", perhaps.) Thes tallitot have, seemingly, hundreds of fringes. It's all meant to be decorative or a nuisance when they get caught in the hinge of a shul folding chair.

Comment: @DonielF completely different question to Little Knots of Wool...  NOT a duplicate.

Comment: You can call them by a different name, but you’re still referring to the same part. If you still think you’re referring to a different part of the Tallis, could you please explain which part you’re referring to?

Comment: @DonielF           In the first place, the 1st comment under the question refers to the question being about the Talit Katan.  2nd place, the 1st ANSWER has no votes, and also refers to the Tait Katan. It is not accepted by the questioner as an answer to his question.  3rd place, the 2nd ANSWER appears basically refers to the Talit Katan also. MY QUESTION refers specifically to the Talit Gadol.

Comment: @DonielF  See also comment above "Weighing in on the dupe suggestion. Unfortunately that question isn't as clear as this one. The upvoted answer there kind of proves it. – user6591 18 hours ago"                 I would appreciate REMOVAL of  "Duplicate" in the question title. Thank you.

Comment: @mbloch , See also comment above "Weighing in on the dupe suggestion. Unfortunately that question isn't as clear as this one. The upvoted answer there kind of proves it. – user6591 18 hours ago"                 I would appreciate REMOVAL of  "Duplicate" in the question title. Thank you.

Comment: @YeruchamDavidbenMordecai the quote is one man opinion while the duplicate vote came from five. I’m afraid there is so much similarity between the questions they are indeed dupe. You can further edit your question to differentiate it from the other if you feel it is indeed different. Or put a bounty on the other one to encourage answers.

Comment: I see that I can't win, even though the first question was about the TALIT KATAN, and mine was not. Let us agree to disagree, Friends? :)

Comment: That question asks about both Tallis Katan and Tallis Gadol, regardless of what part the answers actually address. The body of that question starts with “On most Tallitot and Sephardi Tallitot Ketanot.” You can always place a bounty on that question to attract answers that address the first part as well, if you’d like.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate that, but I will abide by what I said to  @mbloch. I am satisfied with the answers I received before my question was marked "duplicate".